# DOJO - Place within data-dojo-attach-point

Tags: javascript, dojo

```
        this.rows.push(new Row({
            data: this.data
        }, this.body));
```

This will place the new Row widget at `this.body`, `<tbody data-dojo-attach-point="body"></tbody>` - however I want to place the new Row widget *within* the table body, not replace the tbody 'body' attach point with the new Row.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: you're using grid ou what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Row` inherit from a dijit (`_Widget`) , so by default it has a placeAt (see [doc](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.10/dijit/_Widget))function that place your widget to the desired place . so the code would be like

```
this.rows.push(
     new Row({
        data: this.data
     }).placeAt(this.body);
);
```

Otherwise you can reach this last by using the `[dojo/dom-construct][2]` class to place your widget in specific ref

first import the `dojo/dom-construct` -> `domConstruct` then

place you widget inside the table body by using domConstruct.place(node, reference);

```
var row = new Row({
             data: this.data
          });
this.rows.push(row);
domConstruct.place(node.btn.domNode, this.body);
```